# JavaScript Ternary with Logical OR

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, logical-or

```
var a = '1';
console.log(a == ('2'||'1')?'hi':'hello');
```

Doing so the condition get failed as `a = 1` .
It is comparing a's value 1 with 2 as this condition failed. so it always print hello.
Is there any way to check for value('1') also which is after "||" so that it print hi?

Answer (score 5):

Either list the different possibilities out separately:

```
a === '2' || a === '1' ? 'hi' : 'hello'
```

Or use an array and `.includes`:

```
['2', '1'].includes(a) ? 'hi' : 'hello'
```

The problem with `('2'||'1')` is that the whole section there gets evaluated to a single expression before the comparison against `a` is made, and `||` will evaluate to the initial value if it's truthy. So `('2' || '1')` resolves to `'2'`.

Answer (score 0):

var a = 1;
a == '2'?'hi': a=='1'?'hello' :'';

i Found this is also working.... Thanks to everyone who answered using different ways..